# Django Template tags.How to increase the gap between list elements using template tags?

Tags: django-templates

I am using {{value|linebreakers}} for breaking line after each element.

I want to manipulate and add styling to each element of a list that I sent in a dictionary from backend. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have any code that you have written and it's giving a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.7 and above [List Comprehensive](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) works like --:
[ ' {} '.format(x) for x in lst ]

but found no such tags in Django templates have checked Django Docs.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, you have a list items=[item1,item2,....]. You can iterate over it using Django templates.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{item}} # here you can add whatever styling you want to add for each item.
{% endfor %}
```

Also if you have a list of lists you can use nested loops in the same way. 
you can read the [django documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/) for more details.